# R and Simmer insert data into variable

Tags: r

I am trying to store `get_mon_resources` into a data variable.

```
library(simmer) 

SystemTime <- 200
delay= c(20,40,60,80,100,120,140,160,180,200)/60
set.seed(1234)

elevators <-lapply(1:100, function(i) {
  elevator <- simmer("elevator")

  worker <-
    trajectory("elevator service") %>% #trajectory name
    log_("new worker arrived") %>% #
    set_attribute("start_time", function() {now(elevator)}) %>%
    seize("elevator",amount = 1) %>% #elevator queue and service 
    timeout(function() sample(delay,1)) %>%
    log_(function() {paste("Waited: ", now(elevator) - get_attribute(elevator, "start_time"))}) %>%
    release("elevator") 

  elevator %>%
    add_generator("worker", worker, function() rexp(1, 2)) %>% 
    add_resource("elevator", capacity = 2) %>% 
    run(until = SystemTime)
    mydata <- get_mon_resources(elevator)
})
```

but `mydata <- get_mon_resources(elevator)` command line doesn't work

Comment: Have you run the code is it running fine on R?

Comment: Yes, is it running fine

Comment: what do you mean by this :- "  but mydata <- get_mon_resources(elevator) command line doesn't work  " is it throwing any error?

Comment: i dont get error , the problems is that data from  get_mon_resources(elevator) doesnt insert into "mydata" variable

Comment: i want to export the data for each replication into "mydata" variable

Comment: Try the answer and let me know if you still face any issues.

Comment: Is it working? or you are still facing some issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have not declared the mydata variable as global variable because of that you are not able to access the variable outside.Replace  `mydata <- get_mon_resources(elevator)` with the below code

```
mydata <<- get_mon_resources(elevator)
```

Comment: How can i insert data from attribute like the following : "times <<- get_attribute(elevator, "start_time")"

Comment: where do you want to insert?

Comment: after " set_attribute("start_time", function() {now(elevator)}) %>%"

Comment: can you paste some sample output for " get_attribute(elevator, "start_time"). "

Comment: please see my new post included the code. see variable named "Start_times"

Answer (score 0):

```
library(simmer) 

SystemTime <- 200
delay= c(20,40,60,80,100,120,140,160,180,200)/60
Start_times <<-data.frame(row.names=TRUE)

set.seed(1234)

elevators <-lapply(1:10, function(i) {
  elevator <- simmer("elevator")

  worker <-
    trajectory("elevator service") %>% #trajectory name
    log_("new worker arrived") %>% #
    set_attribute("start_time", function() {now(elevator)}) %>%
    seize("elevator",amount = 1) %>% #elevator queue and service 
    timeout(function() sample(delay,1)) %>%
    Start_times<<-rbind(get_attribute(elevator, "start_time"),Start_times)%>%
    log_(function() {paste("Waited: ", now(elevator) - get_attribute(elevator, "start_time"))}) %>%
    release("elevator") 

  elevator %>%
    add_generator("worker", worker, function() rexp(1, 2)) %>% 
    add_resource("elevator", capacity = 2) %>% 
    run(until = SystemTime)




})
```

Comment: your out will be somthing like this{    trajectory: anonymous, 3 activities
{ Activity: SetAttribute | keys: [weight], values: [80], global: 0, mod: N }
{ Activity: SetAttribute | keys: [weight], values: function(), global: 0, mod: N }
{ Activity: Log          | message } }

Answer (score 0):

The `get_mon_*()` methods work just fine for lists of simulations too:

```
library(simmer)

SystemTime <- 200
delay= c(20,40,60,80,100,120,140,160,180,200)/60
set.seed(1234)

elevators <-lapply(1:100, function(i) {
  elevator <- simmer("elevator")

  worker <-
    trajectory("elevator service") %>% #trajectory name
    #log_("new worker arrived") %>% #
    set_attribute("start_time", function() {now(elevator)}) %>%
    seize("elevator",amount = 1) %>% #elevator queue and service 
    timeout(function() sample(delay,1)) %>%
    #log_(function() {paste("Waited: ", now(elevator) - get_attribute(elevator, "start_time"))}) %>%
    release("elevator") 

  elevator %>%
    add_generator("worker", worker, function() rexp(1, 2)) %>% 
    add_resource("elevator", capacity = 2) %>% 
    run(until = SystemTime)
})

mydata <- get_mon_resources(elevators)
head(mydata)
#>   resource     time server queue capacity queue_size system limit replication
#> 1 elevator 1.250879      1     0        2        Inf      1   Inf           1
#> 2 elevator 1.254170      2     0        2        Inf      2   Inf           1
#> 3 elevator 1.420254      2     1        2        Inf      3   Inf           1
#> 4 elevator 1.434505      2     2        2        Inf      4   Inf           1
#> 5 elevator 1.628096      2     3        2        Inf      5   Inf           1
#> 6 elevator 1.673071      2     4        2        Inf      6   Inf           1
```

Comment: thank you , but in this method the replication field value is 1 , how can i increment replication value for each replication ?

Comment: get_mon_resources(elevators) command is fine for me , i have one problem : the "replication" field is every time  is 1, there any way to increment this value by as lapply(1:100, function(i)) ?

Comment: It is not. Run the example and inspect the whole dataset.

Answer (score 0):

[image: replication value every time is one]

How can I increment this value by `lapply(1:10, function(i)` ?